# Can't align shapes vertically, horizontally next to H1

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stack three square-shapes on top of each other, with a h1 placed horizontally next to them, different variations of the display selector, doesn't seem to work, and when it's set up "correct" the h1 "eats" the square shapes.

Html

```
 <div class="squares">
        <div id="square1"></div>
        <div id="square2"></div>
        <div id="square3"></div>
      </div>

      <h1> korius</h1>
```

Css

```
    h1 {
  color: #2d3436;
  font-size: 72px;
  display: inline;
}

.squares {
  display: inline;
}

.squares > div {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

#square1 {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

#square2 {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

#square3 {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
```

[Js-fiddle: All the code](https://jsfiddle.net/b3frgwh2/)

[Image of wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81SiW.png)

Comment: A few small changes (inline-block, change squares > div rule,  and margin) https://jsfiddle.net/2uc6qts1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor changes can help you.. So the parent container of the squares should be displayed `inline-block` so that it can be placed side by side to the text 'korius'. And all the div under `squares` needs to be displayed block so that they are showing vertically.

```
.squares {
  display: inline-block;
}

.squares > div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

Check snippet below:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #2d3436;
  font-size: 72px;
  display: inline;
}

.squares {
  display: inline-block;
}

.squares > div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

#square1 {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

#square2 {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

#square3 {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <title>korius</title>
</head>

<body>



  <div class="squares">
    <div id="square1"></div>
    <div id="square2"></div>
    <div id="square3"></div>
  </div>

  <h1> korius</h1>


</body>

</html>
```

You can also test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/p6mezj9u/).

Comment: Thanks for the help, i struggled with this for way too long! Have a great day!